# How does scanf and getchar work together?

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

I'm confused how scanf can work together with getchar. I was under the assumption that scanf can get the user input and then when the user presses enter it assigns the input respectively. While, getchar works by getting each character and assigning it to the variable getchar was assigned to. Looking at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    int num, i;
    char ch;
    printf("Enter an expression: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n'){
        if (ch == '+'){
            scanf("%d", &num);
            i += num;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Shouldn't I get to input 3 times? The first scanf and then the getchar and then the last scanf, or am I missing something key here? I'm new to C and I hope you don't mind this (probably stupid) question of mine :)

Comment: The key is understanding how `scanf()` processes whitespace, both in the format string and in the input stream, and this varies with the format specifier. The base line is *not* to mix different input functions: if you have to do that to kludge around the way that scanf()` works, then don't use `scanf()` in the first place.

Comment: The `scanf` family is fine for parsing simple inputs. As soon as it's not simple, people should move away from `scanf` rather than believing it is "the way" since that what they were taught. Using `scanf` for an expression sounds like exactly this problem. Use a lexical analyser and parser generator to process more complex grammars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` is not involved in transferring data when the user pressed enter.

C programs have streams of data. (Even though they are handled with a `FILE *` type, they are streams, not files.) `scanf` reads from the standard input stream. Commonly, the standard input stream is connected to a terminal device (in the old days, a physical terminal device, these days, more likely a software terminal window). The terminal device has protocols about when it sends data the user has typed to the stream. Again most commonly, when the user presses enter, the data they have typed is sent to the stream. Also, on Unix systems, pressing control-D sends the typed data to the stream.

To do its work, `scanf` asks the stream for a character. Then it analyzes how the character matches the conversion it is working on. For example, when `scanf` is working on a `%d` conversion, it expects there may be some white-space characters at the start (which it skips), then maybe a “+” or “-”, then some digits. Any other character stops the conversion. So, when `scanf` starts on a `%d` conversion, it gets a character. If no character is available, perhaps because the user has typed something but not yet pressed enter, then `scanf` just sits there waiting until a character arrives. When the user presses enter, `scanf` gets the first character.

Note that `scanf` was not involved in waiting for enter to be pressed. That is a function of the terminal. At this point, `scanf` only has the first character and does not know whether enter was pressed.

After `scanf` reads the digits, it reads the next character. When that character does not match the `%d` pattern, it puts the character back into the stream. So, if the user types “123+456”, `scanf` processes the “123”, gets the “+”, rejects the “+”, and pushes the “+” back into the stream.

Then `getchar` gets the “+” and returns it.

Then the later `scanf` reads the “456”. It also sees the new-line character the terminal put into the stream for the enter key, and it rejects it and pushes it back into the stream.

Comment: Wow this just cleared up so many things for me, so am I correct to assume that all functions that can input shares the same stream? Also is this what they call an Input Buffer?

Comment: @airismything: Yes, every function within a program that use the standard input stream shares the same stream (and it is the same for other streams, when the program opens others). There is typically some buffer inside the stream, although streams can be set not to use a buffer.